# Coldfusion regex to not select an href with specific ID

Tags: regex, coldfusion, html-parsing, coldfusion-9

I have an HTML parser doing the hard work, but I need a regex to select anchors that don't have an attriburte id="optout". Here's my current regex that selects all anchors that have href with http... this is great just needs to ignore those anchors with id="optout" -- any ideas?
Thanks!

```
<cfset matches = ReMatch('<a[^>]*href="http[^"]*"[^>]*>(.+?)</a>', arguments.htmlCode) />
```

Comment: _"I have an HTML parser doing the hard work"_ - then keep using it for the easy work too!

Comment: the way I have it set up needs cf to select the links first... :(

Comment: Then you almost certainly have it setup wrong. HTML parsers are designed explicitly for this task. Regex was originally designed for [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) pattern matching, and even a modern non-regular regex is not well suited to the complexities of HTML parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is the wrong tool for this task, and given that you've already got a HTML parser involved, there's no reason not to keep using it!

Here's the trivial way to do it with a HTML parser ([jsoup](http://jsoup.org)):

```
jsoup.parse( Arguments.HtmlCode ).select('a:not([id=optout])')
```

Here's the far less maintainable regex way to do it:

```
rematch( '(?i)<a\s*(?:(?!id\s*=\s*[''"]optout[''"])[^>])+>(?:[^<]+|<(?!/a>))+</a>' , Arguments.HtmlCode )
```